# Repeat Alarm manager in Sending SMS not Sending

Tags: android, sms, alarmmanager

I created application that if the button is click it will send SMS to the number that came from webservice. Then I use Alarm Manager to send SMS repeatedly in the number that i get from the web service. It is working fine but when I change the number that I want to send an SMS it will not work. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Here is my code.

This is my code that send an SMS.

```
public class EmergencyAssistance extends ActionBarActivity {
    ArrayList<Objects> objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String url = "http://192.168.254.108:8080/taxisafe3/webService/listcontact";
    String urls = "http://192.168.254.108:8080/taxisafe3/webService/plate";
    String contact1;
    String contact2;
    String contact3;
    String contact4;
    String contact5;
    String message;
    String message1;
    Button send;
    LocationService locationService;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    StringBuilder address;
    StringBuffer smsBody;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_assistance);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emergency);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setData();
                new Task().execute(urls);
                new Tasks().execute(url);
            }
        });

    }

    public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String content = HttpULRConnect.getData(url);
            return content;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {
                JSONArray ary = new JSONArray(s);
                for (int i = 0; i < ary.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = ary.getJSONObject(i);
                    Objects objects = new Objects();
                    objects.setCon1(jsonobject.getString("con1"));
                    objects.setCon2(jsonobject.getString("con2"));
                    objects.setCon3(jsonobject.getString("con3"));
                    objects.setCon4(jsonobject.getString("con4"));
                    objects.setCon5(jsonobject.getString("con5"));
                    objectsList.add(objects);

                    contact1 = objects.getCon1();
                    contact2 = objects.getCon2();
                    contact3 = objects.getCon3();
                    contact4 = objects.getCon4();
                    contact5 = objects.getCon5();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public class Tasks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String content = HttpULRConnect.getData(urls);
            return content;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {
                JSONArray ary = new JSONArray(s);
                for (int i = 0; i < ary.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = ary.getJSONObject(i);
                    Objects objects = new Objects();
                    objects.setTaxi_plate_no(jsonobject.getString("taxi_plate_no"));
                    objects.setDriver_operator(jsonobject.getString("driver_operator"));
                    objectsList.add(objects);

                    message = objects.getTaxi_plate_no();
                    message1 = objects.getDriver_operator();

                    emergency();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void emergency() {
            smsBody = new StringBuffer();
            smsBody.append("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=");
            smsBody.append(lat);
            smsBody.append(",");
            smsBody.append(lng);
            String msgs = "[EMERGENCY!] \nTaxi plate #: " + message + "\nTaxi operator: " + message1 + "\n" + address + smsBody.toString();
            try {
                if (PatternChecker.isNotNull(contact1)) {
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EmergencyAssistance.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putCharSequence("num1", contact1);
                    bundle.putCharSequence("msg1", msgs);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(EmergencyAssistance.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1, pendingIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void setData() {
        locationService = new LocationService(getApplication());
        if(locationService.canGetLocation()){
            lat = locationService.getLatitude();
            lng = locationService.getLongitude();
        }else{
            locationService.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        getMyLocationAddress();
    }
    public void getMyLocationAddress() {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);

            if (addresses != null) {

                Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                address  = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    address.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }

            } else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not get address..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Alarm Receiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    String msg;
    String num;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        num = bundle.getString("num1");
        msg = bundle.getString("msg1");

        //Toast.makeText(context, num + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(num, null, msg, null, null);
    }

}
```

This is my manifest to allow sending SMS and to register the alarm receiver.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.group.taxisafe" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.mapv2.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mapv2.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/taxisafe"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="TaxiSafe" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DriverDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_details" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Contacts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReportActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_report" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DriversList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drivers_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DriverAdapter"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_adapter" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EmergencyAssistance"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_emergency_assistance" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayContact"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_contact" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactAdapter"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_adapter" >
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I dont get error. Like what i stated above. It is working fine when it is first run in the cellphone. But when I change the number it won't work again. I don't know why.